# como puedo navegar entre ventanas python

Tags: python, tkinter, buscador

como puedo navegar entre ventanas
pero a una ventana en especifico
por ejemplo tengo una ventana la cual es menu de ahi tengo 2 mas que son para marvel y dc y una es para buscar
pero quiero hacer para que la de buscar pueda ir a la ventana la cual tenga lo de marvel es que en la ventana de marvel tengo informacion de heroes de dicha  franquicia y cada imagen de heroe es un boton el cual abre una ventana con su informacion respectiva

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera. En este código creo una ventana y un Toplevel. En la ventana raiz creo un botón que cuando se presiona cambia el foco al toplevel.

```
from tkinter import *

v1 = Tk()
v1.title("Ventana Raiz")

v2 = Toplevel(v1)
v2.title("Toplevel")

def func():
    #con este comando cambio el foco al toplevel
    v2.focus()


b=Button(text="IR A TOPLEVEL", command=func)
b.pack()
```

Aunque si lo que buscas saber es como crear las dos ventanas, aquí te dejo un link que explica que son los toplevels y como usarlos: https://sodocumentation.net/tkinter/topic/6439/multiple-windows--toplevel-widgets-